# How to change individual images onClick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm beginning a very basic site, and in the navigation bar is a series of images.  I'd like each image to change to a highlighted version of that image when clicked (to indicate which div is being shown).  Looking up a basic way to change an image onClick I found [this page](http://interestingwebs.blogspot.com/2012/09/change-image-onclick-with-javascript.html), but I believe that would only work with one image, since the script uses a single event (changeImage) that would affect every image on the page, even if only one of them was clicked.  What kind of script can I use such that clicking one image will only toggle the change of that one image?  Thanks, your help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind event on each image and change image based on clicked one

```
$("img:eq(0)").on("click",function(){
    this.src = "newimageurl";
});
```